# Matplotlib animation blitting : black zone

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a code to plot an animation with blit enabled.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_fig(num, data, plot, ax) :
    text = None
    if num % 2 == 0 :
        text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, str(num), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes,size=15)
    plot.set_array(data[:, :, num %1500].ravel())
    if text : 
        return pp_color, text,
    else :
        return pp_color,

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.random.rand(60, 50, 1500)
pp_color = plt.pcolormesh(data[:,:, 0], cmap = 'Reds', vmin=np.amin(data), vmax=np.amax(data))
cbar = plt.colorbar()
t1 = cbar.ax.set_title('t1')
plt.axis('equal')
ax.text(0.5, -0.1, 'footnote text', horizontalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes,)
t2 = ax.set_title("t2")
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_fig,
                                   interval=0.1, blit=True, fargs=(data, pp_color, ax))
plt.show()
```

When I run the script I get that : [image]

I have to resize my window to have title, colorbar displayed.
When I comment animation code, first figure frame is correctly displayed.

How can I correctly display my figure without resizing it?

Comment: Does the same happen if you set `interval=10` instead of `0.1`? I suspect what is happening is that the figure doesn't have time to get drawn before the animation with its blitting step starts. Should that be the case it might be worth reporting as issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, increasing interval solves the issue. I added an issue on github https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13143